Running Pyspark
Pyspark functions not working
I am unable to execute a simple python script.Here i go with my source and then the problem
I am trying to make the spark run using Dockercompose services.
version: '2'

services:
  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.5.1
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:192.168.1.129"
  spark-worker:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.5.1
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_USER=spark
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:192.168.1.129"

and my pyspark script is as below
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def main():

    # Create a SparkSession using SparkConf
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .getOrCreate()

    # Create an RDD containing numbers from 1 to 10
    numbers_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, 11))

    # Count the elements in the RDD
    count = numbers_rdd.count()

    #print(f"Count of numbers from 1 to 10 is: {count}")

    # Stop the SparkSession
    spark.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The above script executes and say it started spark successfully if i comment the line calculating count() but it fails when i give stating tuple index out of range etc.
I have installed the python 3.11 and pyspark version as 3.5.Please help me to understand
